# perl: executing stored procedure which uses select

Tags: oracle, perl, stored-procedures, dbi

I am running into some errors when trying to run a stored procedure through Perl.

The following statements work fine in sqlDeveloper and return expected results

```
EXEC alpha.beta.do_something()
```

This does not generate any output, as expected

```
Select alpha.beta.get_something(alpha.STRING_ARRAY('xyz')) from tableName
```

This generates output which is given to us from the DBA guys. It has this format in DB terms: `Output Type:Ref Cursor`. The cursor has two columns, `a` and `b`

When running through Perl, I get errors when running the second statement.

This is the Perl code that I am using:

```
sub execute_procedure {
    my $dbh       = shift;
    my $procedure = shift;

    my $statement = "BEGIN $procedure; END;"
    my $sth;
    eval {$sth = $dbh->prepare($statement);};
    eval {$sth->execute();};

    if ($@) {
        print "failed";
    } else {
        print "passed";
    }
}

# Call 1
execute_procedure($dbh, "alpha.beta.do_something()")

# Call 2
execute_procedure($dbh, "Select alpha.beta.get_something(alpha.STRING_ARRAY('xyz')) from tableName")
```

Call 1 works as expected, does not generate any errors

Call 2 results in this error

> "Select alpha.beta.get_something(alpha.STRING_ARRAY('xyz')) from
>   tableName"        results in :PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this
>   SELECT statement (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char
>   6 in 'BEGIN <*>Select alpha.beta.get_result(alpha.STRING_ARRAY('xyz'))
>   from tableName; END;')

if I remove BEGIN and END from the statement in the `execute_procedure` function like this:

```
# my $statement = "BEGIN $procedure; END;";
my $statement = "$procedure";
```

then it does not generate any error, but it returns a result which I don't know how to parse

```
my $result = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
print Dumper($result)
```

results in:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'alpha.beta.get_result(alpha.STRING_ARRAY(\'xyz\'))' => bless( {}, 'DBI::st' )
};
```

so, my questions are

1. What is the right way to execute a stored procedure which uses the SELECT statement? Should it be called with `BEGIN $procedure; END;` or without the `BEGIN`/`END`?
2. How can I get the actual data from `bless( {}, 'DBI::st' )`? I have tried to use different fetch options: `fetchrow`, `fetchrow_hashref` etc. but I am not able to get the actual data from the object

Comment: This looks very familiar. Have you asked the same thing already during the last few days?

Comment: yes, I did ask this yesterday, but it was missing details and people asked me to provide code. I just updated the other question and will be removing that shortly

Comment: Well now it's super clear. See my answer.

Comment: Note that the `DBI` module will not allow you to `prepare` and `execute` multiple statements at once. Also, it will depend on the database driver whether `$dbh->prepare('BEGIN')` succeeds, and the canonical way to create a transaction is to set `$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0` before executing the transaction, and then `$dbh->commit` or `$dbh->rollback` accordingly. `AutoCommit` is enabled by default, and if you set it to a *false* value then every database action that you request will be logged, waiting to be actioned or discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $VAR1 = { 'alpha.beta.get_result(alpha.STRING_ARRAY(\'xyz\'))' => bless( {}, 'DBI::st' ) };
> ```

The value here is [a DBI statement handle](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#DBI-STATEMENT-HANDLE-OBJECTS). It's the same thing you get when you do `my $sth = $dbh->prepare(...)`. It's probably been executed already, so you can just call any of the fetch methods on it.

```
my $result = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
while (
    my $res = $result->{'alpha.beta.get_result(alpha.STRING_ARRAY(\'xyz\'))'}
        ->fetchrow_hashref
) {
    # ...
}
```

But that looks horrible, and you might not know what the keys are. So you might want to just iterate over all of them.

```
my $result = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
foreach my $key ( keys %${ $result } ) {
    print "Processing results of $key\n";
    while ( my $res = $result->{$key}->fetchrow_hashref ) {
        # do things with the $res

    }
}
```

You just need to figure out a good way to deal with the results. The above loop also works if there is just one key in the hash ref, so you could just use it anyway and hope that there is always just one.

Comment: That works, Thanks! so just to get some clarity on question (1), for stored procedures which return something, running them like "BEGIN $procedure; END;"; is not a good idea ?

Comment: @comatose I don't know. I've not used that syntax before.